# what is the correct way to add check for dangling pointer (in use-after-free case)

Tags: c

```c
        int *p, *p2;
        p = malloc(10);
        free(p);
        p2 = p;  //boom
        if (!p2) //check failed
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "p is invalid, can't do further opertaion with p\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
```

Here I tried to check the dangling pointer just like checking null-pointer deference, but this is not working. More reasoning in below:

For checking null pointer, we could do like this

```c
int *p;
p = NULL;
if (!p)
{
    //handling exception
}
```

This does not work for the dangling pointer case like mentioned above, since it is not null.

```c
        int *p, *p2;
        p = malloc(10);
        free(p);
//      p2 = p;
        printf("value: %d\n", *p);
//      if (!p2)
//      {
//              fprintf(stderr, "p is NULL, can't do further opertaion with p\n");
//              exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
//      }
```

```
./a.out
value: 898138160
```

So under this case, what is the correct way to write the check for detecting dangling pointer under use-after-free? (not depending on using tools like ASan)

Comment: there is no portable way to detect a danlging pointer, some heap implementations do have such things.

Comment: I had an idea: since the dangling pointer basically points to a random memory region now, is there a way to check that memory is accessible without triggering page fault?

Comment: `free(p); p=NULL;` ? This is not a solution for dangling pointers but may solve the problem you described.

Comment: @Bubba *>I had an idea* Pointer validity has nothing common with memory accessibility. Dereferencing invalid pointer may cause memory access error or may not.

Comment: @dimich, although whatever scope is doing `free(p)` really needs to have its address, so more likely `free(*p); *p = NULL;`

Comment: most likely a dangling pointer still points to a valid memory address, just not memory that pointer now owns

Comment: @Elliott Why `*p`? `p` is just a pointer to something, not a pointer to pointer to something.

Comment: @dimich, yes, that's my point. If the pointer is being created and destroyed within the one function, then it's a pretty trivial case and you probably don't need any tricks to work out if it's dangling. More practically it'll be because it's being passed around, if function `foo` frees the pointer, then setting it to null will have no effect outside the scope of the function unless `foo` has a pointer to `p`.

Comment: @Elliott Then we can invent smart pointers with reference counter :)

Comment: @dimich, yeah - we're reinventing the wheel a bit here, I think!  =)

Comment: C does not provide a way to check for dangling pointers. But some compilers (gcc, clang, msvc) have a feature called [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) that will detect when the program tries to dereference a dangling pointer.

Comment: @ bubba: But why do you need to detect the "dangling" part? Why is it not enough to detect a NULL pointer and move forward from there? The comment of @dimich gives you the best solution.